# PTIJ: What were the Amish doing in Padan Aram?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Breishit 31:42, Yaakov reproves Lavan for accusing him of stealing his terafim, among other items. In making his case, Yaakov says:

... את עניי ואת יגיע כפי ראה אלוקים ויוכח אמש

G-d saw my affliction and the toil of my palms and the Amish proved it (i.e., the Amish came to support Ya'akov's statement.)

It seems that the Amish watched Ya'akov's sheep herding and maybe helped him along. But, I had no idea that the Amish group actually existed at the ancient time or ever lived in that region of the world in Padan Aram. This is one of the few references in the Torah to the Amish, incidentally. It doesn't say much about them.

Are there any commentaries. Midrashim, or other sources that provide more details as to when the Amish settled in Padan Aram and how Ya'akov got involved with them?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).